# Use variables outside the function

Tags: jquery, variables

Below I am getting the long/lat for an address with the google api. But the variables for longitude and latitube I need to use where gmap. is creating the map_canvas.

How is it done to use these variables in the next function? (Where the long/lat is written per now with numbers)

Jquery:

```
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = markerInformation = $('#googleMapLocation').val();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    } 
    }); 
    markerInformation = $('#googleMapInformation').val();
           $(function() { 
            demo.add(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 10, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                    var self = this;
                    self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {
                        self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': markerInformation }, this);
                    }); 
                }});
            }).load();

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in two ways one is to turn them into global variables by simply removing the reserved word `var` before the variable name.

or you could call the function inside a function

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you can use jQuery's [data method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store and retrieve arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

Just add marker using API:

```
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { position: latitude + ',' + longitude });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine! Except it doesn't center at the position? I'm getting the center over West Africa

Comment: Maybe need to switch? position: longitude + ',' + latitude

Comment: Could be it! But its actually putting the marker on the map on the right position, but its not centering at the position

Comment: API is poorly documented. After that try calling $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': ... })